# Incorrect CASE syntax

Tags: mysql

Here’s my query:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN COUNT(o) > 0 THEN true ELSE false
FROM orders o
left join shop_order so on o.id=so.order_id
left join order_details od on so.id=od.shop_order_id
left join offers of on od.offer_id=of.id
WHERE of.offer_type_id=1
and of.type=2
and o.customer_id = ?1
and od.varient_id=?2
```

the error is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM orders o left join shop_order so on o.id=so.order_id left join order_det

Comment: missing `END` for `CASE`

Comment: Your problem is an SQL syntax error, which has nothing whatsoever to do with JPA or even Java; your question was edited to reflect that. Since the only part of the query at the point in the query the error message quotes is the CASE, the title was narrowed to just that aspect of your query.

Answer (score 2):

The `case` is missing the `end` keyword. Insert `END` before `FROM`:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN COUNT(o) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END
FROM ...
```

MySQL error messages say “near”, but they really mean “right before”.